# Cant drop into a ItemsControl when underlying source is empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I am working on a DragDrop implementation for a new concept, kind of like a dashboard of sorts. Everything works as intended and the DragDrop works indeed, ***except when the ItemsSource is empty***.

I am following `MVVM`, so I am populating different `StackPanel`'s with their own `ItemsControl` from an `ObservableCollection`, from there I can DragDrop between different `ObservableCollections`, this is working except as I mentioned above, when the underlying `ObservableCollection` is empty, I can't drop into the `ItemsControl`.

From debugging this issue, I have notice that the `ItemsControl` height resizes as needed depending on the objects in the collection. When I add an item, the height grows, removing an item it resizes as well.

If bind to the `StackPanel` height property **it works**, but then my I have a big gap at the bottom of the control, this is because I set the `MinHeight` of my `ItemsControl` to the `Height` of it's `StackPanel`. If I do not do this, when there are no items in the collection, I can't DragDrop into it.

Here below is when I do not have anything into one of the columns (`StackPanel`), the underlying source is empty. I can't drop here because the height of the `ItemsControl` is 0 and therefore a hit test can't be done from my understanding.

[image]

Here is the 'gap' I get when I bind to the corresponding `StackPanel`...

[image]

This gap is because I am bound to the `StackPanel` height, and at this time a resize doesn't occur because I now have a `MinHeight` on my `ItemsControl` which prevent's the resize of the `StackPanel`.

Has anyone else experienced this, I can't seem to find a solution as to why the `ItemsControl` does not fill the `StackPanel`, its size is dependent on the underlying source. Can I somehow force the `ItemsControl` height to be what the `StackPanel` is and not have to set the `MinHeight`?

Here is my `XAML` so you can get a better understanding of my issue.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel AllowDrop="True" x:Name="StackOne" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,3" Background="White">
                <ItemsControl Background="White" x:Name="TileColumnOne" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceColumnOne, Mode=TwoWay}"                                     
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
                    <!--MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=StackOne, Path=ActualHeight}"-->

                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel AllowDrop="True" x:Name="StackTwo" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2,3" Background="White">
                <ItemsControl Background="White" x:Name="TileColumnTwo" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceColumnTwo, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
                    <!--MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=StackTwo, Path=ActualHeight}"-->

                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel AllowDrop="True" x:Name="StackThree" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="5" Margin="2,3" Background="White">
                <ItemsControl Background="White" x:Name="TileColumnThree" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceColumnThree, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
                    <!--MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=StackThree, Path=ActualHeight}"
                              >-->                    
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel AllowDrop="True" x:Name="StackFour"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="7" Margin="2,3" Background="White">
                <ItemsControl Background="White" x:Name="TileColumnFour" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceColumnFour, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
                    <!--MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=StackFour, Path=ActualHeight}"
                    >-->                    
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: *so I am populating different StackPanel's with their own ItemsControl from an ObservableCollection* wait, you have a viewmodel with an OC property full of UI elements? That ain't mvvm.

Comment: @Will How would you recommend showing different `UserControl`s then? All of the tiles are different, that is a wrapper. The wrapper wraps the `UserControl` itself and these can be anything. Also I am populating an `ItemsControl`, not a `StackPanel`, maybe I should re-word that :)

Comment: Don't you know how DataTemplates work in WPF? DataTemplates + ContentControls/ItemsControls + MVVM = magic sauce.  You do it right, you just bind your models/view models to the UI and everything else is wired together for you.

Comment: So what is wrong with binding to a collection of views? Either I provide them already or create a template right?

Comment: UI in your view models is not MVVM.  But then, the pattern is here to serve us, not the other way around. If it's working for you, roll on. But the real power in MVVM is in data templates. You're missing out if you don't learn about them. Good luck.

Comment: @Will I do use them, but in this case every view is different. Each view does have it's own ViewModel/Model.... Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix and it's working great if anyone else should come across this issue.

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TileColumnOne,Path=ItemsSource.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding ElementName=StackOne, Path=ActualHeight}" />
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ItemsControl.Style>
```

I had to create a trigger and then bind that data trigger to its corresponding `StackPanel` based on the count of the `ItemsSource`.